# GWT Refresh a page to a History Token

Tags: gwt, browser, browser-history

I have been using History tokens to save the state of my application, and am able to simply use the back and forward buttons, using the tutorial given here : 
http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Tutorials~History_Support

However, I want to know if its possible that, when I press the refresh button, instead of my application restarted from the beginning, can I start it from a specific history token that I may have ? Or keep the view I previously had (for which I also have a history token), that is, before pressing the refresh button ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using Activities and Places design pattern, which extends GWT's history management:

[Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)